# Phpunit which assertion failed?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have some tests for a function and when I run them I get this info:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) myTests::testExamples
Failed asserting that true matches expected false.
```

The tests are below. My question is, how am I supposed to know which assertion failed? Do I need to add messages to each one to get this info?

```
class myTests extends TestCase {
    public function testExamples() {
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'at'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'fluffy'), false);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cheeze', 'ee'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('snow', 'o'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'top'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'zzz'), false);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'pussy'), false);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('octopus', 'tops'), false);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('ababc', 'abc'), true);
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('abc', 'abc'), true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least two alternative approaches spring to mind:

- Adding messages to your asserts
- Changing test scheme

### Adding messages

Most, if not all, of the `assertSomething` functions accepts a third parameter which is a messages string shown when the assert fails. In other words, you could change your tests to be:

```
$this->assertEquals(isSubStr('ababc', 'abc'), true, "ababc vs ab");
$this->assertEquals(isSubStr('ababc', 'abc'), true, "isSubStr: entire string");
```

If doing this, make sure the message is unique, and helpful for you to locate the given assert.

### Change test scheme

One really old, but really useful test scheme is the [Assign Act Assert](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert) test scheme. This implies that any given test function should only test one particular function/action. If it fails, you'll know exactly which one is failing, and can target this one directly.

In your case this could look like:

```
class testIsSubStr extends TestCase {

    public function test_cat_vs_at_true() {
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'at'), true);
    }

    public function test_ababc_vs_abc_true() {
        $this->assertEquals(isSubStr('cat', 'at'), true);
    }

    // Full scale with arrange - act - assert
    public function test_octopus_vs_zzz_false() {
        // Arrange
        $expect = false;
        $inputText = "octopus";
        $inputSub = "zzz";

        // Act
        $actual = isSubStr($inputText, $inputSub);

        // Assert
        $this->assertEquals($actual, $expect);
    }
}
```

Notice how the class name reflects the function you're focusing these tests on, and that the function names indicates the input parameters. As before, choose names properly helping you identify what it tests.

The last example shows a *proper* arrange-act-assert function, which is more useful for larger cases where there is a point in arranging something, e.g. building up lists, before you act on it, and afterwards maybe do some changes before you can assert it.

The main trick still is to separate out the test into several functions, so that if any given function fails you'll know exactly where the assertion failed.

A final note; There is some debate whether it is illegal to have multiple assertions when you have a complex arrangement to test. Possibly your code returns an object with multiple changes, and you want to test all the changes. If you opt to do multiple asserts, I would strongly recommend combining both of these ideas and add proper messages to help you identify which assertion actually failed. (And do note that with multiple assertions, you might need multiple test runs to remove all of the failed assertions, as one fail stops that test function).